# Error converting Python containing lxml to exe

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, lxml, py2exe

I am trying to convert a Python script to executable using py2exe. The script includes the lxml library. When I run my `dev_setup.py`  I get

```
C:\Python33\Scripts>python dev_setup.py py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev_setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lxml import _elementhpath as _dummy
ImportError: cannot import name _elementhpath
```

Here’s`dev_steup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from lxml import _elementhpath as _dummy
import py2exe

setup(console=['dev/read_config.py'])
```

I also tried

```
setup(
    windows=[{'script': 'dev/ps_attr_read_config.py'}],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip'],
        }
    } )
```

and this produced an executable but the executable just runs and closes. I've also tried `packages=['C:/Python33/Lib/site-packages/lxml'],` I know the [documentation](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules) says

> if missing _elementhpath, either pull whole lxml library in
>   packages=..., or put "from lxml import _elementhpath as _dummy"
>   somewhere in code; in both cases also pull gzip in packages=...

but I can’t understand what it’s talking about? How can I convert the python script using lxml, to exe?

Comment: Are you still experiencing the same issue?

Comment: @mabe02 I no longer work on this project